# Firemonkey: Getting parent form of control

Tags: c++, forms, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I have a custom control which needs to get access to the height of the main form it is on.  Since it is common for this control to be nested in a series of panels, I have written this code to try and get me to the main form:

```
TControl * control = this;

while( control->HasParent() )
{
    control = control->ParentControl;
    ShowMessage( control->Name );
}
```

Using the `ShowMessage` statement to track my progress, as I step through the code I get all the way up to "BasePanel" which in this case is the last control up the ladder before the "MainForm."  However, when the call to `ShowMessage` happens for what should be the "MainForm" I get an access violation.

Is there some reason I am unable to access the main form of a control this way?  Is there a better way to access a control's main form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if `ParentControl` returns a NULL pointer before reading its `Name`.  When `HasParent()` returns true, `ParentControl` is *NOT* guaranteed to be valid.  Case in point - `TForm` is *NOT* a `TControl` descendant in FireMonkey, so it cannot be returned by `ParentControl`.

The purpose of `HasParent()` is to report whether the component has a parent or not.  `TFmxObject` overrides `HasParent()` to report whether the `TFmxObject.Parent` property is NULL, and overrides `GetParentComponent()` to return an appropriate `TComponent` for that parent.  `TFmxObject.Parent` returns a `TFmxObject`, as parent/child relationships do not have to be visual in FireMonkey like they do in VCL, so `Parent` and `GetParentComponent()` can actually return different objects at times.

You should be using `GetParentComponent()` instead of `ParentControl`, as the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.HasParent) says:

> Call [HasParent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TComponent.HasParent) to determine whether a specific component has a parent.
>
> Derived classes override this method to implement proper handling for parenting.
>
> **Use [GetParentComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TComponent.GetParentComponent) to retrieve the component reference.**

For example:

```
TComponent * comp = this;

while( comp->HasParent() )
{
    comp = comp->GetParentComponent();
    ShowMessage( comp->Name );
}
```

However, if your intent is to find the parent `TForm` specifically, use your control's [`Root`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Root) property instead:

```
TCommonCustomForm *form = dynamic_cast<TCommonCustomForm*>(this->Root->GetObject());
```